# Compare rows against a date column and return matches

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV.  It has 7 or 8 columns but I need to compare 2 against each other.  An email column against a date column.  The two columns I need have headers of "email" and "passwordlastset".

I'd like to just do an `Import-Csv` and where row(s) match `$inactive` I need it to grab those email addresses and send an email.  I already have the email code ready I just need a good way to grab my list of emails against the column that has the dates.  The following isn't working.  I need some guidance on this if possible.

```
$daysInactive = 14
$inactive = (Get-Date).AddDays("-$daysInactive")
$Users = Import-Csv c:\query.csv | where {$_.passwordlastset -eq $inactive}
```

It would be nice to do like above but if I need to import the original CSV and dump a new one that is fine.

Where am I going wrong?

As requested here are csv headers:

[headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itcsy.png)

I need to take all entries in the email column that meet a date in the passwordlastset column.

Comment: Define "isn't working". What output do you expect? What output do you actually get? Are you getting errors? If so, what do they say?

Comment: One thing you could change is the `{$_.passwordlastset -eq $inactive}` to `{$_.passwordlastset -lt $inactive}`. Otherwise you only look for password the are equal to today's date minus 14 days, not the ones that were already "expired"

Comment: Not working meaning it's returning nothing unfortunately.  I did try the -lt and same behavior.  When I test against the $inactive variable it returns whatever day corresponds to $daysinactive so that seems to be fine.

Comment: When i use:    Import-Csv C:\query.csv | where {$_.passwordlastset -as [datetime] -lt $inactive} it returns everyone on the list and doesn't seem to check date

Comment: Can you also show an example of the csv you're inputting?